# Keras Conv2d Transpose

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, convolution

I am trying to use Keras to create a Fully Convolutional network for image processing. My initial grid is (10x25) and I pass that through couple of convolutional layers and then try to use Conv2d Transpose to try and resize the image back to original dimensions, however my deconvolutional layer has no output or is coming as none rather. You can look at the code to see what is being done.

```
inputs = Input(shape = (input_shape)) 
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding ='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (2, 2), strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding = 'same')(conv1)

conv2 = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding = 'same')(conv2)

 conv3 = Conv2D(128, (2, 2), strides = 1,  activation='relu', padding ='same')(pool2)
 conv3 = Conv2D(128, (2, 2), strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same') (conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding = 'same')(conv3)

deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size = (pool3.get_shape().as_list()[1:3]), strides = (2,2), data_format='channels_last')(conv3)
  conv4 = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same')(deconv1)

deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size = (conv1.get_shape().as_list()[1:3]), strides = (2,2), data_format='channels_last')(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(32, (2, 2),strides = 1, activation='relu', padding ='same')(deconv2)

deconv3 =  Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size = (input_shape[0:2]), data_format='channels_last')(conv5)
conv6 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), strides = 1,  activation=act_identity)(deconv3)
```

Comment: What do you mean? Where is the definition of your model? Where is the line where you find the error? What is the error and its stack trace?

Comment: So the main problem is with the fact that if you look at the output shape of the deconv1 is coming as none (except for the number of channels). Assuming that the implementation of the conv2dTranspose is correct, its output dimensions should be what I have mentioned right ?

Comment: Isn't your input shape  `(None,None,3)`? How are you getting this output shape? Even though, you don't need to care about this. The best place to look at the shapes is `model.summary()` after you define the model.

Comment: Oh wow, the summary is giving me enough information to understand the shapes of each layer. But I think what I need to know is that  if I want to take a 4x4 grid as input and then obtain a 10x10 grid with say 64 channels. I couldnt find much examples of how it is being implemented, and was under the impression that the kernel_size would be your needed output (thought I understand the name seems to imply anything but that).

Comment: Use `UpSampling2D` to double size. This is the opposite of `MaxPooling2D`. Use `Conv2DTranspose` to add borders related to the kernel size. Filters (3,3) will add 1pixel at each side. But since you're using `padding='same'` everywhere, I'd use normal convolutions with `padding='same'` too. If the shapes are not matching, its because your initial image must be a multiple of 8 (2³ because of 3 maxpooling layers).

Comment: The initial image is a 10x25 image. But that is not the problem, like for a particular input, kernel size and stride how do you estimate the output from a `Conv2DTranspose`

Comment: The exact opposite of a Conv2D with `padding='valid'`. Conv2D removes borders based on filter size. Conv2DTranspose adds them.